# TypeError: Cannot read property 'ChangeClassName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop

The following code returns me TypeError on this.ChangeClassName method calling. What's the problem? I tried using without "this". It's important to call a nested method in another method in the same class.

```
import React from 'react'
import styling from '../Login/Login.css'

class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            active: false,
        }

        this.ChangeClassName = this.ChangeClassName.bind(this);

    }

    ChangeClassName() {
        this.setState({
            active: true
        });
    }

    LoginClick (event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        this.ChangeClassName();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="login-page">
                <div className={ this.state.active ? 'form color-change-5x': 'form' }>
                    <form className="login-form">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="username" />
                        <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
                        <button onClick={this.LoginClick}>login</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: is it because `LoginClick` has not been bound also?

Comment: It works, thanks! Do I need to bind every single method if there's used state update? Even if state update is in a nested method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're binding `ChangeClassName` inside your constructor, which is fine. The problem is you're calling it from within `LoginClick`.

`LoginClick` is not bound to anything so `this.ChangeClassName` translates to calling `ChangeClassName` on a different scope.

Try adding the bind for that method as well:

```
this.ChangeClassName = this.ChangeClassName.bind(this);
this.LoginClick = this.LoginClick.bind(this);
```